# PyInstaller: AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'register'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, attributeerror

I am working on a large python project where at the end the scripts are packaged by PyInstaller. Last week I had no issues packaging and running my application. This week I have no errors with packing my script. However, when I run my executable now I seem to be getting a rather generic error, but coming from a strange source:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 120, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 271, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/tmp/build/tmpDJZeLr/out00-PYZ.pyz/encodings", line 157, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register'
```

I went looking within my code to find the culprit, but nowhere within my project is there an attribute/function/etc called 'register'. I tried to add some debug statements within my own code, but not a single function within my scripts gets called before this error pops up.

I then decided to add some print statements within pyi_importers.py near line 70:

```
            sys.modules[fullname] = module
            # Run the module code.
            print module
            print module.__dict__
            print bytecode
            exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
```

The results were:

```
<module 'encodings.aliases' from '/tmp/_MEIbDiUZq/encodings/aliases.pyc'>
{'__name__': 'encodings.aliases', '__file__': '/tmp/_MEIbDiUZq/encodings/aliases.pyc', '__loader__': <pyi_importers.FrozenImporter object at 0x7f1666fa0d10>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'encodings'}
<code object <module> at 0x7f1666fb4f30, file "/tmp/build/tmpg_2pIX/out00-PYZ.pyz/encodings.aliases", line 17>
Traceback (most recent call last):...
```

I took a look around and discovered that the encodings.aliases has to do with built-in python libraries. I am using Python 2.7.6 and PyInstaller 2.1; which should be compatible according to their documentation. I am working within a cloud base IDE (c9), but doesn't seem like that should be the issue since this is a python and not OS issue.

I am stumped. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

The issue was with a package name conflict. Within my project was a package named 'codecs'. When the python standard library hooks were being processed by PyInstaller, the namespace of my project trumped the Python standard library's. In turn this caused the encodings.aliases module to import my projects 'codecs' module rather than the encodings module.